# Why in logs I can see "[39m[38 5" all over (azure log analytics )? What does this mean?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-log-analytics

We are logging all our application logs in log Analytics .If I see the logs in log analytics i can see
"[39m[38 5" this text all over place. What does it mean?

```
[39m[38 5 145m200812 07:46:49[39m[38 5 188m [39m[38 5 107mINFO [39m[38 5 188m Operation_Id=[39m[38 5 85m12345[39m[38 5 188m
```

Comment: could be some formatting information (like coloring) used in the original log message. Sometimes you can configure your log output to use something like `-no-color`

Comment: Thanks @silent it was indeed because of color formatting. After making logs color false there is no ASCI  characters in my logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Suggested by @silent on original question I made logs color option to false and I don't see ASCI character in my logs anymore.

Exact properties I changed in my application.properties file.

```
quarkus.log.console.color=false
```